# Java Singleton instance and BasicDataSource potential Memory Leak?

Tags: java, database, spring, memory-leaks, singleton

Forgive me if this is answered already, though I searched and could not find information that left me confident that I could make a determination one way or the other. So here is my question.

I am extending a Spring application and have written a library of Java classes that manage a separate Database table (in a separate database altogether from the DB the Spring app uses). Thus, my classes are used inside the Beanshell namespace within this application.

I have written my main Class to leverage the Initialization-on-demand holder idiom. So you basically get an Instance of my class, which uses the BasicDataSource to interact with my Database. Certain interactions (possibly more that I am aware, as it is being tested by another analyst at the moment) cause the JVM to hang. I believe it has something to do with the DB Connection.

I have methods like updateRecord(String), updateMultipleRecords(List ...), etc. I these methods, wrapped in try/catch/finally statements are an openConnection() method in TRY and closeConnection() in FINALLY.

Here is the holder...

```
private static class MyClassHolder {
    private static final MyClass INSTANCE = new MyClass();
}

/**
 * Returns the Singleton instance of MyClass
 * @return The/an Instance of {@link MyClass}
 */
public static MyClass getInstance(){
    return MyClassHolder.INSTANCE;
}
```

And here is one of the problematic methods...

```
public RequestStatus addToList(List<String> ids) {
    RequestStatus status;
    try{
        openConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY_UPDATE_BLACKLIST);
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++){
            MyClassStatus resStatus = checkIdStatus(ids.get(i));
            if (MyClassStatus.AVAILABLE == resStatus){
                stmt.setString(1, ids.get(i));
                stmt.addBatch();
            } else {
                // This should be a log statement
                System.out.println("NOT MODIFYING " + ids.get(i) + ": STATUS IS: " + resStatus);
            }
        }
        stmt.executeBatch();
        status = RequestStatus.SUCCESS;
    } catch (SQLException ex){
        status = RequestStatus.FAIL;
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeConnection();
    }
    return status;
}
```

and the open and close connection methods...

```
/**
 * Just a method to open a database connection
 */
private void openConnection(){
    if (conn == null){
        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Just a method to close an open database connection
 */
private void closeConnection(){
    if (conn != null){
        try{
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqlex){
            sqlex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Could this pattern be causing a memory leak? I don't have access to the system it is being tested on right now, so I cannot run profiling tools of any sort. So I am trying to rule out the obvious pattern issues with this first.

Any help would be appreciated. If more information is needed, I am happy to provide more.

Thank you!

Comment: Half of your question is the explanation of why did you do some decisions, which is really irrelevant. Second part doesn't represent any details of implementation that may be relevant (by details I mean code). It is impossible to help you using the information you've provided.

Comment: The information provided is to add context, in case that context is relevant. So as not to be confused with my classes running in their own Classloaded jvm. They are loaded with the Application that I am extending. And they are used inside the Beanshell namespace within that app (in case this too has implications). I have not posted a ton of questions on here, so if there is a better way to format this question, I would be happy to do so. I will update the original with code samples, but I am not sure what changes to make to provide proper context.

Comment: You need to focus on details, try to eliminate everything not related to the issue. And then add the smallest amount of code you can to represent the place which, in your opinion, causes the issue. However TBH usually the best way is to find a way to reproduce the bug at your local machine, and then use all the great tools that Java world provides.

Comment: Updated with more and less informaton, per @user3707125

Comment: What about `conn` field? Is it synchronized correctly? Is there a possibility that multiple threads access `openConnection` simultaneously?

Comment: Also why aren't you setting `conn` to `null` in `closeConnection`?